# why my next.js app's apiroutes always 405 err

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using edge route in this project. Although it works perfectly in my local environment. Deploying to aws or vercel always gives me a 405 error. can anyone help ?

here's my client code

```
const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            signal: controller.signal,
            body,
        });
```

and here's my server(api route) code

```
    export const config = {
    runtime: 'edge',
};

export default async function handler (req: Request): Promise<Response> {
 const headers = {
                'Allow': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET,DELETE,PUT',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL || '',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET,DELETE,PUT',
            };
            return new Response(body, {
                status: 200,
                statusText:'success',
                headers:headers
            });
}
```

and.............. here's my deploy console

[image]

**response headers "Allow" is something wrong, I think I've tried all the usual solutions
...what can I do ?**

Comment: are you using `generateStaticParams` ?

Comment: no... i use only api route

Comment: @kysclient Is it right to set Allow Methods to response headers? In my case, when I used express server, I set express cors middleware to set network configurations. Here is the DOCS https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html